# Adding custom internal method to a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new with RoR and I have a controller (`UsersController`) where I wish to verify the existence of a certain session before anything. Since the session verification code is the same for several methods and I don't want to repeat myself, I decided to make a new method in my controller to check the sessions:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
        if self.has_register_session?
            # Does something
        else
            # Does something else
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def create
    end

    def update
    end

    def destroy
    end

    def self.has_register_session?
        # true or false
    end
end
```

And when I run the page `/users/new`, I got this error:

```
undefined method `has_register_session?' for #<UsersController:0x1036d9b48>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Why are you making `has_register_session?` a method on the class rather than the instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`self` when you define the method refers to the `UsersController` class object, but within the instance method `new`, `self` refers to the *instance* of `UsersController`.

1. You can either make your method an instance method:

   ```
   def has_register_session?
     # code
   end
   ```

   You can then get rid of the `self` when calling `has_register_session?` in `new` as well.
2. Or call the method on the class:

   ```
   if UsersController.has_register_session?
     # code
   end
   ```

   instead of referencing `UsersController` explicitly you could do `self.class`.

Note that you likely want the first solution: making `has_register_session?` an instance method.

Answer (score 0):

By doing `def self.blah` you've created a class method whereas you want an instance method.

You might also want to make the method protected - all public methods are exposed as actions by default.